# Laravel Seed: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, seeding

I building Twitter clone app use Laravel5.4 and [While referring to this](https://medium.com/@just4sky/rebuild-twitter-with-laravel-timeline-2a2b63ca8e1b)

now i want seeding database with test data

in my terminal input `php artisan db:seed --class=TweetsTableSeeder`
 got error

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add
  or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`twitter`.
  `tweets`, CONSTRAINT `tweets_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_
  id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

I read the error and tried to understand, but I had no good results.
I'm looking at the official document but I can not understand much because  beginner.

so please help me

2017_07_09_create_tweets_table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTweetsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tweets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('body', 140);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tweets');
    }
}
```

Tweet.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tweet extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'body',
    ];
}
```

TweetsTableSeeder

```
<?php

use App\Tweet;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class TweetsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(Tweet::class, 10)->create([
        'user_id' => 2
        ]);
    }
}
```

ModelFactory.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Model Factories
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may define all of your model factories. Model factories give
| you a convenient way to create models for testing and seeding your
| database. Just tell the factory how a default model should look.
|
*/

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    static $password;

    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});

$factory->define(App\Tweet::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'body' => $faker->realText(140),
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add   or update a child
>   row: a foreign key constraint fails (`twitter`.   `tweets`, CONSTRAINT
>   `tweets_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_   id`) REFERENCES `users`
>   (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

The above error simply means that you are trying to `seed` (insert) a value in `tweets` table and that value is not available in the parent `users` table.

In layman terms, when two tables are sharing `foreign key` relationship, then only those values can be inserted into child table that are already present in parent table, and in your case you are violating the above stated rule.

Comment: Thank you for reply.  Thank you for the easy-to-understand answer. In order to insert this seed I should change the content that is in violation right?　If you can, please tell me which part to fix ?

Comment: Sometimes the solution is so easy and you can't even see it! Thanks!!

Comment: @christostsang enjoy the coffee and happy coding ;)

Comment: As a rule of thumb its better if you follow the sequence of your migrations when you build your DatabaseSeeder.php file.